# Trying to use Merge twice within an ifelse statement

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements

I am trying to use an ifelse statement paired with another ifelse statement that uses 2 merge statements for the conditions. Below is what I got

```
newest_mld$Segment <-
  ifelse(
    newest_mld$Datacapturekey == "No Match",
    "No Match",
    ifelse(
      newest_mld$Datacapturekey == "Call Campaign",
      merge(
        newest_mld,
        unique(mld_map_seg),
        by.x = "Campaign.Code",
        by.y = "X8",
        all.x = TRUE
      ),
      merge(
        newest_mld,
        unique(mld_lead_seg),
        by.x = "Datacapturekey",
        by.y = "DATACAPTUREKEY",
        all.x = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
```

Although my new column "Segment" comes out weird

Is it possible to do conditional merges?

[image: Far right column is the one that comes out as C(''..)]

Comment: the value of `merge` is a dataframe, and you are trying to assign this to a single column. I expect this is what is causing your problem.  If you give a sample of your data and show the expected output it wil be easier to advise.

Comment: My guess is that you will likely need to `merge` twice and only then try to do conditional reassignment with possibly nested `ifelse`s.